# Pass parameters to factory pattern Architecture in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to implement factory pattern Architecture. I have created Interface with parameterized function.

1) Step 1 :

```
public  interface IDatabase
    {
        bool Create(string userId,string password,string host,string dbName);
        bool Delete(string userId, string password, string host, string dbName);
    }
```

Step 2:

This interface is Implemented in below class:-

```
public class IntialDBSetup : IDatabase
    {    
        public bool Create(string userId, string password, string host, string dbName)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + host + ";uid=" + userId + ";pwd=" + password + "");
            try
            {    
                string strCreatecmd = "create database " + dbName + "";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCreatecmd, con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                var file = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScriptLocation"]));
                string strscript = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
                string strupdatescript = strscript.Replace("[OWpress]", dbName);
                var server = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection(con));
                server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(strupdatescript);
                con.Close();
                return true;    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;    
            }               
        }    
        public bool Delete(string userId, string password, string host, string dbName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Step 3:

created factory class

```
public class DBFactory
{
   public static IDatabase DbSetup(string DbType, string userId, string password, string host, string dbName)
   {
       try
       {
           if (DbType == DBTypeEnum.IntialDB.ToString())
           {               
               return new IntialDBSetup();
           }             
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           throw new ArgumentException("DB Type Does not exist in our Record");             
       }
       return null;           
   }
}
```

Here I want to pass some parameter to my class, Hgow can I get this?

Comment: Shouldn't you call the `Create` method on your `new InitialDBSetup()`?

Comment: A factory is generally responsible for returning an instantiated object.  That's what yours does.  I guess you're asking for your factory to perform an action (`Create`) on that object?  Generally that's something the person calling the factory would do.  Not that what you're doing is bad, I just don't think you need a factory here really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a constructor to your class.

If `DBFactory` and `IntialDBSetup` are in the same assembly then that constructor can be marked `internal` (preventing code outside the assembly creating instances directly).

If the factory method was a `static` member of `IntialDBSetup` then the constructor can be `private` preventing direct creation even in the same assembly.